# Which yuga did Panini live in?

Tags: history, sanskrit, panini

Which Yuga did the sanskrit grammarian [Panini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81%E1%B9%87ini) live in according to Hindu tradition?

Comment: I dont think he lived before vyasa of current dwaparayuga.. he is current only in kaliyuga.. maybe even after buddha also.. because he made fundamental flaws in missing  the alphabets like zha, ilzha which is one of the alphabets in tamil, kannada other southindian languages..   because of which many veda mantra are wrongly printed like "sammulzdha masya pammsure" describe universe as speck of dust from the feat of lord..

Comment: @PrasannaR, what ? zha is unique to Tamil. Are you saying it should have been in Sanskrit too ?

Comment: 3 la in tamil out of which one lazha is unique to tamil other 2 is common across all language he missed despite vedas use them

Answer (score 3):

Pāṇini lived in the Kaliyuga as per Hindu tradition. Chapter 179 of the Pratisarga Parva (second khaṇḍa) of the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa throws light in this regard:

> आसीत्पुरा **कलियुगे** पितृशर्मा द्विजोत्तमः। वेदवेदांगतत्त्वज्ञो यमलोकभयान्वितः॥४॥
>
> Earlier **in the Kaliyuga** lived the foremost of Brahmins named Pitṛśarmā. He had knowledge of the Vedas and Vedangas and was afraid of committing sins (of Yamaloka). (4)
>
> चत्वारश्चात्मजाश्चासंश्चतुर्वेदैक्यधारिणः॥२७॥
> ऋग्यजुश्च तथा साम तुर्यश्चासीदथर्वणः।
>
> He had four sons who were knowers of the four Vedas and their names were Rik, Yajus, Saman and Atharvan. (27b and 28a)
>
> पाणिनिः सामनस्यैव सुतोऽभूच्छब्दपालः॥२९॥
>
> Saman’s son was **Pāṇini who was a grammarian**. (29b). Gitapress translation says: who excelled in the field of grammar.

Thus we can see that Pāṇini was the grandson of an eminent Brahmin of the Kaliyuga named Pitṛśarmā, and accordingly his life is to be placed in the Kaliyuga only.